# Do you get points if you are broken/trapped in Saboteur 2

Tags: saboteur-2

In Saboteur, if the good dwarves reach the gold, they distribute points to themselves but skip over any good dwarves with broken equipment.

Does this rule still apply for point distribution in Saboteur 2, or does your broken status not matter for collecting points after a round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It does not.**  *Note that this rule is optional in the original rule set.*

[Answered by the Designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/6688742#6688742), Frederic Moyersoen on BGG:

> The broken tools variant was introduced to have some competition between the gold-diggers.
>
> The extension provides more chaos and competition. Therefore, this variant rule has been skipped during the design of the game. However, if you wish, you can still use it.